# How to change "Build Order" in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My solution has the following projects:

```
project1
project2
project3
project4
testproject
```

`testproject` has no connection with all other projects in the solution.
Whenever I start to debug the `testproject`, the VS always tries to compile/build all other `projectX`. Here is my finding:

Under the **Project Dependencies**, I didn't choose any `projectX`.
However, under the **build order**, the VS lists all projectX+testproject there.

Is there a way that I can tell VS don't compile/build projectX when I debug testproject?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you right-click your solution from within Visual Studio and select properties a dialog box will pop up allowing you to setup different solution configuration behavior. You can create a test or debug configuration and choose which projects you want to build or not build.

[image: Solution Property Pages]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle this:

Right click any project you don't want to build, and select "`Unload project`". It will be "greyed out" and inactive. When want it back, right click and select "`Reload project`".